# Why price with lower volatility yield higher expectation under risk neutral measure

Tags: risk, risk-neutral-measure, asset-pricing

Suppose $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two asset prices, such that, E[$S_1$] = E[$S_2$] under physical measure and $\sigma(S_1)$ > $\sigma(S_2)$. Then why E[$S_1$] < E[$S_2$] under the risk neutral probability measure? How can we prove or disprove this?

Comment: All asset prices have the same expected return under the risk-neutral measure $Q$. For example, under a Black-Scholes model, $E^Q(S_1(t))=S_1(0)e^{rt}$ where $r$ is the risk-free rate. So $E^Q(S_1(t))<E^Q(S_2(t))$ if and only if $S_1(0)<S_2(0)$. Do you mean rather why $E^Q(S(t))<E^P(S(t))$ where $P$ is the physical measure?

Comment: Hi @DaneelOlivaw, The final comparison is in risk neutral measure Q between asset $S_1$ and asset $S_2$, $E^Q(S_1(t))$ < $E^Q(S_2(t))$. we don't know $S_1(0)$ and $S_2(0)$ here. In another way, the question is if $E^P(S_1(t))$ = $E^P(S_2(t))$ and $S_1$ has higher volatility, then the risk neutral discounted price $S_1(0)$ < $S_2(0)$.

Comment: The result is quite intuitive. Imagine that you have two stocks which have the same expected return, same current price but the first one is more volatile. Definitely, any rationale investor would go for the second one which is less risky. An investor will only go for the first one if he gets a lower price for the extra volatility that he is ready to take. If you want a more formal proof, you can express the difference between P and Q, also called the market price of risk as a function of the volatility. If the volatility increases, the expected return should increase as well. Hope it helps.